# Inheriting multiple roles to deploy CDK [AWS, Python]

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to create some CDK infrastructure that is on a different AWS account to my service account but I'm struggling with understanding how to complete it. I use python and CDK v2.

My service account (i.e. where my cdk bootstrap is set up) is my CDK deployment account. I do not have direct access to this account, so I have to inherit a role in order to use it. I have a profile set up that means that my cdk commands are issued with the --profile command.

`cdk deploy --profile **service-account-profile**`

The --profile command defines a region, and also a role-arn parameter;

`role-arn arn:aws:iam::{**serviceaccount**}:role/CDKenabledRole`

The CDK bootstrap user accounts are in the **serviceaccount**.

This then gives me access to deploy CDK infrastructure on the service account, which I have done many times over based on different requirements.

## The problem;

I have been asked to create a subscription to a topic, that subscribes to a SQS on my **serviceaccount**. The topic is on a different account, lets call it the **clientaccount**.

I have been given a IAM role that allows me to complete the subscription on the **clientaccount**. This role is represented by arn:aws:iam::{**clientaccount**}:role/SubscriberEnabledRole`

The IAM role above can only be inherited by my service account, so I have no direct access, I need to essentially inherit my service account role, and then inherit the client account role.

I am supposed to use my CDK command to assume the clientaccount role above and create a subscription.

My basic code to create a subscription is a method that loks like this;

```
topic_arn = f'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:{source_topic_account}:{source_topic_name}'
 queue_arn = f'arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:{analytics_aws_account}:{target_queue_name}'

topic = self.collect_topic_from_arn(topic_arn, source_topic_name)
queue = self.collect_queue_from_arn(queue_arn, target_queue_name)

print(f'Creating new subscription on topic {topic_arn} for queue {queue_arn}')

subscription = sns_sub.SqsSubscription(
    queue=queue, 
)        

topic.add_subscription(subscription)


def collect_queue_from_arn(self, arn, queue_name):
    #locate existing topic arn
    queue = sqs.Queue.from_queue_arn(scope=self,
        id=queue_name,
        queue_arn=arn
    )
    return queue


def collect_topic_from_arn(self, arn, topic_name):
    #locate existing topic arn
    topic = sns.Topic.from_topic_arn(scope=self,
        id=topic_name,
        topic_arn=arn
    )
    return topic
```

I can't quite grasp how to inherit another role to synthesize the stack, or to deploy the code.

I'm looking to understand:

- The process to create a subscription in my client account.
- What permissions each of my bootstrap roles would need to make this happen.

## Additional information;

- arn:aws:iam::{**clientaccount**}:role/SubscriberEnabledRole has the sns:* allowable permissions.
- arn:aws:iam::{**clientaccount**}:role/SubscriberEnabledRole also has an sts:assumeRole allowable permission also.

I tried writing some code using boto3 and gaining a number of role assumptions but that quickly became very convoluted, and there must be an easier way to deal with it.

I have also tried adding a --role-arn explicitly in my cdk command like so;
`cdk --role-arn arn:aws:iam::{**clientaccount**}:role/SubscriberEnabledRole deploy --profile **service-account-profile**`, but I get a error `cross-account pass role is not allowed.`

Comment: You can't do this natively in CloudFormation - your stack cannot create/modify resources in another environment. You'd have to bootstrap the target account with a `--trust` flag do trust your deployment account and deploy a stack into that account. You can also use a lambda-backed custom resource as an alternative.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks @gshpychka. Have you got any documentation for the lambda-backed custom resource?

Comment: Sure: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources-readme.html

Comment: I ended up doing this via boto3 in the end, creating a new STS session with the appropriate credentials, and then executing my tasks within the session. Thanks for your help with the above.